# Алгоритм работы с текстом

Tags: редактор-текста, алгоритм, ms-word

Подскажите, есть ли возможность в програме Word или ином текстовом редакторе выполнить следующий алгоритм.

Скопировать в буфер обмена устройства все слова, которые заключены в двойные кавычки, в документе.

Пример:  понятие, отражающее "**поведение**" товаропроизводителя на рынке, его "**готовность**" произвести (предложить) какое-либо.

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В диалоговом окне Поиска и Замены можете в поле Найти ввести “*”, поставить галочку "Выделить все элементы, найденные в" и выбрать "Основной документ" (например). Поставить галочку "Подстановочные знаки" (нажмите кнопку БОЛЬШЕ, если этого пункта не видно). Будут выделены все слова, заключенные в кавычки, причем стоит учесть, что символ * - означает любое количество знаков.

---

Если нужно, чтобы данная процедура проходила автоматически, можно использовать макрос.

[Поиск и замена текста с помощью регулярных выражений (расширенные возможности)](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f?ui=ru-RU&rs=ru-RU&ad=RU)